# Xiaomi M8SE Fastboot loop when trying to install TWRP

Tags: adb, twrp, fastboot, xiaomi

When trying to install TWRP (latest version for Xiaomi Mi 8SE) I manage to install the newest TWRP using adb (fastboot flash recovery "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot\twrp.img).
However, once I boot into TWRP, it does not set it as a default loader.
After wiping the data, and trying to reboot in recovery like here: https://youtu.be/FEN7Ujb4vdo?t=390 it simply reboots into fastboot and from there, I cannot do anything anymore.
I then have to install a Chinese developer version using MiFlash.

Can someone help me with this issue? I am trying to install a xiaomi.eu MIUI 11 version for my better half - she is tired of the Chinese ROM and half of the OS is in Chinese...

Comment: you don't need TWRP for MIUI global, please be more specific

Comment: I thought that the only way to flash it is by using TWRP. But now I managed to install TWRP (see my anser). Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

The solution to get out of the fastboot loop was to fresh install the developer MIUI with the MI Flash tool and then sign into the MI Account when setting up the phone. This is essential and the only way to install TWRP. I am guessing it has to verify that the bootloader is unlocked with the Mi account first.